# Javascript convert yyyy-mm-ddTHH:MM:SS to DAY of week (MON) HH:MM AM/PM

Tags: javascript, date, datetime

I have a format like this

```
2017-02-14T11:30:00
```

Which I want to convert to

```
Fri Feb 14 11:30 PM
```

Yes, I don't know what day of the week it is so I put in "Fri"  and then that PM is probably supposed to be an AM

with Javascript I was previously passing in completely different data so this function needs more modifications

```
var getTravelDateFormatted = function () {
    // Example  Mon Jan 23 
    return function (str) {
        var daysNames = ['Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat'],
            monthNames = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sept', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'],
            d = new Date(str),
            day = d.getDate(),
            month = monthNames[d.getMonth()],
            year = d.getFullYear().toString().substr(2, 2),
            dayName = daysNames[d.getDay()];

        //return day + '-' + month + '-' + year + ' (' + dayName + ')';
        return dayName + ' ' + month + ' ' + day;
    };
};
```

Thoughts on how to do this?

Comment: If you're working with dates and willing to include a library in your project,  `moment.js` makes this very easy and has great documentation

Comment: IRL, I suggest just using a library that does this for you. Dojo has a wonderful module for this https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dojo/date/locale/format.html, but there's also smaller libraries that do the same like DateJS https://code.google.com/archive/p/datejs/wikis/APIDocumentation.wiki. Of course, if you're just trying to figure this out for educational purposes, we can help with that...

Comment: I believe another guy already has moment.js in the project  - i need to figure out how to use it

Comment: @JeremyMiller - no need for external libraries . . . for formats like these, the `toLocalString` method in the native JS `Date` object offers a lot of options.

Comment: @talemyn—the built–in Date object's *toLocal**e**String* offers zero options and is implementation dependent. I get different results in Safari and Firefox. Some implementations support the ECMA-402 Intl object, but it is not ubiquitous.

Comment: @RobG - I've got an answer below using `toLocaleString` that does (almost) exactly what he wanted with only the options accepted by the method.  The only extra step that was needed was to strip out the commas that were added.  It won't work for every date format out there, but it is a good fit for his use case.

Comment: @talemyn—likely it "works" in the browsers you tried, but it's not reliable as a general solution for the reasons in my previous comment.

Comment: @RobG - Did you test my solution, or have you just run into browser differences with `toLocaleString` in the past?  I'm getting the same result in both IE and Chrome (Firefox is temporarily blocked on my work computer . . . don't get me started   >:(   ),

Comment: @talemyn— *I get different results in Safari and Firefox*, and there are perhaps hundreds of browsers in use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var getTravelDateFormatted = function() {
    // Example  Mon Jan 23 
    return function(str) {
        var daysNames = ['Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat'],
          monthNames = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sept', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'],
          d = new Date(str),
          day = d.getDate(),
          month = monthNames[d.getMonth()],
          year = d.getFullYear().toString().substr(2, 2),
          hours = d.getHours(),
          minutes = d.getMinutes(),
          dayName = daysNames[d.getDay()];

        //return day + '-' + month + '-' + year + ' (' + dayName + ')';
        return hours > 12 ? (dayName + ' ' + month + ' ' + day + ' ' + (hours - 12) + ":" + minutes + " PM"):
          (dayName + ' ' + month + ' ' + day + ' ' + hours + ":" + minutes + " AM");
          };
        }();

  
        var formatedDate = getTravelDateFormatted('2017-02-14T11:30:00');
        console.log(formatedDate);
```

Comment: This works ,  thx!    I am wondering if I really should start using moment.js instead of having to have several new date functions per month or year of development    ....

Comment: moments.js it's a  great library , it's more easy with it

Comment: like it seems that this would do the same thing  `var blah = "2017-02-14T12:40:00";`   then
  `console.log(moment(blah).format('ddd MMM DD HH:mm a'));`

Comment: @JeremyMiller—yes, **if** there was a moment.js tag. The OP could also use `fecha.format(fecha.parse(s, 'YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss'), 'ddd MMM D, hh:mm a')`, but there's no [*Fecha.js*](https://github.com/taylorhakes/fecha) tag… ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing more details around what you are trying to format this date for, you could do this pretty quickly with the `toLocaleString` method of the vanilla JS `Date` object.  There are a ton of options that let you output date/time values in the way that you'd like (lots of details can be found on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString)).

So, once you have your value, you could do something like this with it:

```
function formatDate(dDate) {
    var oFormatOptions = {
        weekday: "short",
        month: "short",
        day: "numeric",
        hour: "numeric",
        minute: "numeric"
    };

    return dDate.toLocaleString("en-US", oFormatOptions);
}
```

Now, using your original "February 14 at 11:30 in the morning" example, your return value would be: `Tue, Feb 14, 11:30 AM`.  If the commas are not acceptable, you could remove them by changing the last line to:

```
return dDate.toLocaleString("en-US", oFormatOptions).replace(/,/g, "");
```

That would result in exactly the value that you were asking for: `Tue Feb 14 11:30 AM`

Check out what the function has to offer . . . there is a lot of flexibility to play with.

Answer (score 0):

You don't necessarily need the arrays that contain the days of the week and the months.

The date object when converted to a string actually contains the info you need.  you could do something like this:

```
/**
A date object will produce a string like this:
*"Tue Jan 10 2017 16:51:05 GMT-0500 (EST)"
* Maybe this is good enough?
*/

var myDateObj = new Date();
var dateParts = myDateObj.toString().split(' ');
var myDay = dateParts[0];
var myMonth = dateParts[1];
var myDate = dateParts[2];
var myHour = myDateObj.getHours();
var myMin = myDateObj.getMinutes();
var ampm = 'AM';

if (myHour > 11) {
    ampm = 'PM';

    if (myHour !== 12) {
        myHour = myHour - 12;
    }
}

var dateText = myDay + ' ' + myMonth + ' ' +  
    myDate + ' ' + myHour + ':' + myMin + ' ' + ampm;

console.log(dateText);
```

Comment: You are relying on *Date.toString* to produce a particular output, but it is implementation dependent so may not be what you expect.